# image as not shown as properly on intervention/image

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, intervention

I am using an intervention/image package on laravel but without a refresh page to not show the image properly. once refresh the pages only to show on images. my code as below,

```
$productid = ProductImage::find($id);
$filePath = base_path()."/storage/app/".$productid->productimage; 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$img = Image::make($filePath);
return $img->response('jpg');
```

Comment: If I'm not getting this wrong, I guess you are saying that without refreshing a page you wan to show a newly created image on the page, right ?

Comment: yes,but not newly created one,existing images sometimes show empty image icon